# Adding in a ng-repeat loop to get a total (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, foreach, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table that displays the number of hours an employee has worked. The data is in $scope.dailytimes. In each row there is a column called time that shows how many hours were worked in the day. I need a way to loop through each row and add the times together. So if there were 4 rows of results and the employee worked 3 hours each day my total would be 4. Hours worked per day varies so I can't just multiply.

I have started something like this but it isn't working.

```
 $http({
        url: '/SharedData/DailyTime',
        method: 'POST'
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.dailytimes = data
        $scope.total = function () {
            var total = 0
            angular.forEach($scope.dailytimes, function(dailytime){ 
                total += total + dailytime.time
            })
            return total;
        }
    })
```

Here is my ng-repeat:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="dailytime in dailytimes" style="line-height:18px;">
    <td width="50" style="font-weight:bold;">
       <div ng-if="dailytime.ClockType == 0">Vacation</div>
       <div ng-if="dailytime.ClockType == 1">PTO</div>
       <div ng-if="dailytime.ClockType != 0 || dailytime.ClockType != 1">Clocked</div>
    </td>
    <td width="70" align="right" style="font-size:12px;"> {{dailytime.ClockIn}}</td>
    <td width="70" align="right" style="font-size:12px;">{{dailytime.ClockOut}}</td>
    <td width="40" align="right">{{dailytime.time}}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="line-height:18px;">
    <td style="font-weight:bold;">Total</td>
    <td colspan="3" align="right" style="font-weight:bold;">NEED A TOTAL HERE</td>
 </tr>
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make total() function accessible in a controller or somewhere and use that one like following

```
<td colspan="3" align="right" style="font-weight:bold;">{{total() }}</td>
```

Comment: I just want to highlight that `total += total + dailytime.time` should be changed to `total += dailytime.time` for the addition makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

define a totaltime varaible on scope

```
  $scope.totaltime=0;
  $scope.updateTotal = function(t){
    $scope.totaltime =  $scope.totaltime +t;
return t;
  }
```

now in repeat

```
 <td width="40" align="right">{{updateTotal(dailytime.time)}}</td>
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. That just wrote out {{$scope.totaltime+=dailytime.time}} and broke angular. It did not display any numbers. I am also not sure this would work because I have multiple dailytime.time logs that I need to add. And at this point in my code I am outside of my loop.

Comment: I got it figured out. Thanks!